# JDBC4: The Index 6 Is Out Of Range When 6th parameter is NOT NULL after a series of NULL parameters

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

UnsignedByte is defined to be 0-255. .getValue() returns Short.

pts1, pts2, pts3 are ALL null or ALL not null (input checks beforehand guarantee).

addlevel(...)'s CallableStatement WORKS for these scenarios:

1. (gameNo, levelNo, **null**, **null**, **null**, **null**)
2. (gameNo, levelNo, pts1, pts2, pts3, **null**)
3. (gameNo, levelNo, pts1, pts2, pts3, typeNo)

but throws

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 6 is out of
>   range.

on:

(gameNo, levelNo, **null**, **null**, **null**, typeNo)

the right statement called is marked with a comment in java code segment.

.......................................................................................................................................

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addLevel
@gameNo int,
@levelNo int,
@pts1 int = NULL,
@pts2 int = NULL,
@pts3 int = NULL,
@typeNo tinyint = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO tblLevel (gameNo, levelNo, pointsForStar1, pointsForStar2, pointsForStar3, typeNo)
     VALUES (@gameNo, @levelNo, @pts1, @pts2, @pts3, @typeNo)
END
GO
```

java:

```
public boolean addLevel(int gameNo, int levelNo, Integer pts1star, Integer pts2star, Integer pts3star, UnsignedByte typeNo){
    try{
        CallableStatement cstmt;
        if (pts1star != null){
            if (typeNo != null)
                cstmt = database.getConnection().prepareCall("{call dbo.addLevel(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
            else
                cstmt = database.getConnection().prepareCall("{call dbo.addLevel(?,?,?,?,?)}");
            cstmt.setInt("pts1", pts1star);
            cstmt.setInt("pts2", pts2star);
            cstmt.setInt("pts3", pts3star);
        }
        else{
            if (typeNo != null)
                cstmt = database.getConnection().prepareCall("{call dbo.addLevel(?,?,?)}"); //<<<<<--------------- THIS ONE
            else
                cstmt = database.getConnection().prepareCall("{call dbo.addLevel(?,?)}");
        }
        cstmt.setInt("gameNo", gameNo);
        cstmt.setInt("levelNo", levelNo);
        if (typeNo != null)
            cstmt.setShort("typeNo", typeNo.getValue());
        cstmt.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored procedure support in Java is positional (even if you use the parameter names to set the parameter value). `typeNo` is parameter 6 of your stored procedure. Your 'faulty' call defines three parameters. Parameter three is `pts1`. You need to always call the six parameter version if you want to set `typeNo` and explicitly `setNull` the parameters that don't have a value.

Specifically for SQL Server, the `{call dbo.addLevel(?,?)}` is translated to something like the following (with positional parameters):

```
EXEC dbo.addLevel ?, ?, ?
```

When you set the parameter value by name, the driver looks up the parameter position, and attempts to set that parameter. `typeNo` is position six, so it tries to set parameter 6, which is not defined in this query.

In SQL Server when you execute a stored procedure, you can leave out **trailing** positional parameters with defaults, or you need to explicitly specify the parameter name (assuming all other parameters have a default):

```
EXEC dbo.addLevel @gameNo=?, @levelNo=?, @typeNo=?
```

As far as I know you should be able to use the above query with `CallableStatement` instead of the `call`-escape (although I believe this will require using the parameter position to set the value, and not by name).