# How to call a stored procedure without including all parameters with default values?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data JPA application calling a SQL Server stored procedure. The stored procedure has 25 parameters with the first parameter being an `OUT` parameter. All other parameters are `IN` and have a default value of null.

```
create procedure [pHistory]
      @CarData varbinary(max) out
     ,@CarIds nvarchar(max) = null
     ,@Color nvarchar(max) = null
     -- several more optional params with default value = null
     ,@Model nvarchar(max) = null
     ,@Make nvarchar(max) = null
     -- a few more optional params with default value = null
```

I want to call the stored procedure with only two of the `IN` parameters.

In T-SQL, this is easily done via:

```
DECLARE @Model nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Make nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @CarData varbinary(max)

SET @Model = 'Nissan'
SET @Make = '240SX'

EXEC pHistory
     @CarData out
    ,@Model = @Model 
    ,@Make =@Make
```

With my Spring application, I'm trying this as follows:

```
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Car, Long> {

    @Procedure
    Blob getCarData(
            @Param("@Model") String model, 
            @Param("@Make") LocalDate make);
}

@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "Car.getCarData", procedureName = "pHistory", parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "@CarData", type = Blob.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@Model", type = String.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@Make", type = String.class)})
public class Car {

    @Id
    private String carHistoryId;
// other data...
```

But when I call `getCarData`, I'm getting

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 11 is out of range.`

This seems to be because the call is being prepared as :

```
{call pHistory(?,?,?)}
```

But the `@Model` parameter is at position 11. So, when JDBC tries to bind a value to the parameter at position 11, it fails (since there are only three parameters in the `{call pHistory(?,?,?)}`).

If the parameters could be bound, I'm guessing it would call the stored procedure without named parameters:

```
EXEC pHistory @Cardata out, 'Nissan', '240SX'
```

Is there a way using Spring Data JPA to call the stored procedure without specifying all of the optional parameters (i.e. parameters with default values)?

**Update**

I can call my procedure using named stored procedure parameters using `CallableStatement`. So, this allows me to specify only the parameters that I want:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=dbName", "user", "pass");
CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{call pHistory(@CarData=?, @Model=?, @Make=?)}");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1,Types.BLOB);
stmt.setString(2,"Nissan");  
stmt.setString(3,"240SX");  
stmt.execute();
```

This works. And I know that I can use a `@Query` with my Spring Data repo and specify `nativeQuery=true`. I also know that I could create a wrapper stored procedure on the database (if I had permissions) that only had the params that I need.

But does Spring Data have a feature for calling a stored procedure with named parameters?

**Update 2**

I tried with JPA:

```
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = 
              entityManager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("pHistory",Car.class)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .setParameter(2, "Nissan")
                .setParameter(3, "240SX");
    
           
   storedProcedure.execute();
```

According to [its (`StoredProcedureQuery`) Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html):

> The setParameter methods are used to set the values of all required IN and INOUT parameters. **It is not required to set the values of stored procedure parameters for which default values have been defined by the stored procedure.**

So, this should I work, but I'm getting index out of range error. I'm sure Spring Data is using this (via Hibernate 5.4) under the hood.

**Update 3**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39924401/jpa-can-a-stored-procedure-be-called-without-providing-optional-parameters) does not help me because jTDS does not support SQL Server 2019. Also, the second solution in the post recommended a wrapper. That also does not work for me since I don't have DB access for those changes.

Comment: Related: [JDBC4: The Index 6 Is Out Of Range When 6th parameter is NOT NULL after a series of NULL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889897/jdbc4-the-index-6-is-out-of-range-when-6th-parameter-is-not-null-after-a-series)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Thanks for the link. I read that prior to posting, and your answer there was very helpful. I can use `CallableStatement` to do the job, but I'd like to use Spring Data if it offers that capability. Updated my post to show some options I've considered if that capability is not there.

Comment: I believe you upvoted my answer on that question, which is why I had the link ready ;). I posted it as a cross-reference (can be helpful if other people land here with a similar issue). Unfortunately, I don't usually use stored procedures from Spring Data JPA, so I'm not sure if there is an option or not, but my first thought is that there isn't.

Comment: Ah ok. Makes sense. Thanks for your comments.